# Show $|1-e^{ix}|^2=2(1-\cos x)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show $|1-e^{ix}|^2=2(1-\cos x)$

$$|1-e^{ix}||1-e^{ix}|=1-2e^{ix}+e^{2ix}=e^{ix}(e^{-ix}-2+e^{ix})=e^{ix}(2\cos x-2)=-2e^{ix}(1-\cos x)$$

Not sure how they got rid of the $-e^{ix}$ factor. Did I expand the absolute values wrong? thank you

Comment: You computed $(1-e^{ix})^2$, not $\lvert 1-e^{ix}\rvert^2$. That would be $(1-e^{ix})(1-e^{-ix})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|1-e^{i x}|^2 = (1-e^{i x}) (1-e^{-i x}) $$

Then use $e^{i x}+e^{-i x} = 2 \cos{x}$.

Generally, $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$ |1-e^{ix}|^{2} = |1-\cos x - i \sin x|^{2} = (1-\cos x)^{2} + (-\sin x)^{2} = 1 - 2 \cos x + \cos^{2} x + \sin^{2} x $$

$$= 2 - 2 \cos x$$

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$$

Then $$\left|1 - e^{ix}\right|^2 = |1 - (\cos x + i\sin x)|^2$$

Can you take it from here? Or, expand $$\left|1-e^{i x}\right|^2 = (1-e^{i x}) (1-e^{-i x})$$ and then use the identity above.

Comment: Gets a vote! =1